# How to add ID in a tree view

Tags: c#, winforms

i am having a problem regarding a tree view control. I am very new to C# and stuck on how to add ID to the corresponding tree nodes. I am not sure whether this lines of code holds ID or if not then what should i include. I want to get the ID of the selected node. How do i proceed please let me know. My code is given below -

Thanks in advance.

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        treeDepartments.Nodes.Clear();

        String strConn = "Server =server;Database =DB;Integrated Security = True;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tSubDepartments", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter daCategories = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tDepartments", conn);
        da.Fill(ds, "tSubDepartments");
        daCategories.Fill(ds, "tDepartments");

        ds.Relations.Add("Dept_SubDept", ds.Tables["tDepartments"].Columns["dpCode"], ds.Tables["tSubDepartments"].Columns["dpCode"]);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tDepartments"].Rows)
        {

            TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["dpName"].ToString());
            foreach (DataRow drChild in dr.GetChildRows("Dept_SubDept"))
            {

                tn.Nodes.Add(drChild["sdName"].ToString());

            }

            treeDepartments.Nodes.Add(tn);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the Name property.

Comment: FYI, you have some bad habits in your code. Your `SqlConnection`, and  both `SqlDataAdapter` instances, should be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that, according to the code, you are working in WinForms so my answer will be based on that presumption. 
`ThreeNode` object has the `Tag` property (like any Control class in WinForms) of type object in which you can store whatever you want but you should be careful to cast it back into type when you want to use it later. So you could change your code like this:

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    treeDepartments.Nodes.Clear();

    String strConn = "Server =server;Database =DB;Integrated Security = True;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tSubDepartments", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter daCategories = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tDepartments", conn);
    da.Fill(ds, "tSubDepartments");
    daCategories.Fill(ds, "tDepartments");

    ds.Relations.Add("Dept_SubDept", ds.Tables["tDepartments"].Columns["dpCode"], ds.Tables["tSubDepartments"].Columns["dpCode"]);
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tDepartments"].Rows)
    {

        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["dpName"].ToString());
        tn.Tag = dr["dpID"]; //put the ID into the Tag property of the node
        foreach (DataRow drChild in dr.GetChildRows("Dept_SubDept"))
        {

             TreeNode childTn = new TreeNode(drChild["sdName"].ToString());
             childTn.Tag = drChild["sdID"];
             tn.Nodes.Add(childTn);

        }

        treeDepartments.Nodes.Add(tn);

    }
}
```

and when you want to extract the ID of the `TreeNode`, just use it like this (presuming that ID is of type `int`):

```
int ID = (int)tn.Tag;
```